# Execute function as string

Tags: javascript

How can I execute a Javascript function such this:

```
cursor.continue(parameters)
```

By using a string to identify the function name, **without** using `eval`? Something like this:

```
cursor.callMethod("continue", parameters);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: @MelanciaUK: I don't believe it is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Ian I've retracted my vote. Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use the square bracket notation.

```
cursor["continue"](parameters)
```

`cursor["continue"]` is exactly the same as `cursor.continue`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in control of `callMethod`, and the function belongs to an object or is global, then yes, that's possible.

For example, if the target function is a method of the same object where callMethod is:

```
var cursor = {
    callMethod: function(method, params) {
        this[method].apply(this, params);
    },
    continue: function() {}
}
cursor.callMethod("continue", [1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `cursor` is an IndexedDB cursor, so techfoobar's solution is more appropriate, but definitely +1 for the literal implementation of my example method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call the function like so:

```
cursor["continue"](parameters);
```